# How do I calculate the amount of 3 Fluids, where 2 are a percentage of the first?

Tags: percentages

I have 3 Fluids:

- Base
- Flavor1
- Flavor2

The target is to have 50 ml of overall produce, where 10% are Flavor1 and 5% are Flavor2. If I just calculate it off the 50 ml, I end up with 57.5 ml, which is not how this is supposed to work.

How do I calculate how much I need of each fluid?

Comment: I am sorry for asking such, for you, basic question, but my math somehow left me today. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you forget that you only need $85$% base?

Comment: @TomTseng But if I use only 42.5 ml of Base, then 5 ml wouldn't be 10% anymore. 10% would be 4.25 ml.

Comment: The flavour percentages are not given with respect to the base, but rather of the whole. So for instance, $5\%$ of the $50ml$, i.e. $2.5ml$, are flavour 2.

Answer (score 0):

According to your clarification, you want something like:
$$y=0.1x\\
z=0.05x\\
x+y+z=50\\
1.15x=50$$

Outside of that, it would be
$$y=(0.1)(50)\\
z=(0.05)(50)\\
x+y+z=50$$